# Where does the groovy http-builder module live now?

Tags: java, http, groovy

The documentation for for the groovy [http-builder](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder/http-builder) module used to live here-ish: http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/groovy/modules/http-builder/http-builder

After codehaus shut down did http-builder and HttpClient get moved / did apache start maintaining them? I'm wondering if there's newer-than-2014 version anywhere and where I could find up to date documentation? Google is not being helpful so clearly I'm searching for the wrong things.

Comment: Are you looking specifically for the old one or http-builder-ng?

Comment: @DaveNewton both if the old one is still around anywhere and if http-builder-ng is the closest successor to http-builder (even if only in a Russian Federation to USSR kind of way). Also, if http-builder-ng is the closest successor, is it better (more stable, more widely used, etc) than apache http components? (at least in the context of the groovy ecosystem)

Comment: @DaveNewton maybe a related question is whether apache http components or http-builder-ng is more commonly used in the groovy ecosystem. Interested if you or anyone else has any thoughts on that.

Comment: https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki

Comment: @daggett, I don't think this question is going to get much more attention. If you put that in an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classic HttpBuilder is located here

https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki

you could grab it from [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder/http-builder) using following annotation in groovy code:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7.1')
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
...
```

---

There is also a newer fork HttpBuilder-NG referenced in the documentation above

https://github.com/http-builder-ng/http-builder-ng